# Uninstalled the Pages URI module and then re-installed it again... lost all my data and my site crashed.... HOW TO RESTORE

Tags: pages

I had an issue with my MSM where it didnt allow me to "Submit" my entry and I have googled for the error and then I came across an answer which said to delete the "Pages" module. I did so and I didnt realize that I was going to hit hard by that step. Alfter I did that all my URLs got messed up.

I have around 1000 channel entries which basically make up my college website.

Is there anyway I can restore all the URLs..?? Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend restoring the site from a backup.  Your host provide should be able to help you gain access to the backups of the file system and of the database, if you don't have direct access yourself and/or you don't have a separate backup available.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, if somehow I can get hold of the DB backup of lets say "yesterday".... can I get all the Urls back...??

Comment: Can you please point me to a list of steps...I'm just wondering if its a normal database recovery that I should do or anything else involved..??  Thanks so much..!!

Comment: Your host should be able to do the actual DB restore for you so you won't have to do anything. If no, they'll most likely provide you with an SQL dump from which you can restore... best to make a backup of the current damaged DB first, then dump all tables, then import the backup.

Comment: NOTE TOO: When you uninstall addons in EE, there is a great potential for data loss if that addon stores data in the DB. For example, uninstalling a field type will cause data loss if any fields use it.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl: Thanks for the response. Our site is hosted on a VM. And our webmaster says that the best he can do is revert it back 48 hours and start it from there. I'm not sure if I can really get a SQL dump (hopefully I should), but what if the database was set up in a way that automatic back ups are not made on a regular basis..? what do you think of a worst case scenario?

Comment: If he reverts 48 hrs, you won't need a dump... he'll be restoring all files on the server including the database. You absolutely need to get proper backups in place. Buy http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/backup-pro right now and get your backups pushing to an offsite location ASAP.

Comment: It should just be a normal database recovery, yes. You would just need to get a copy of your database timestamped before you made your major change - and import it into your database, thereby undoing the changes that you made (make sure a file backup is also part of what you restore).

Comment: Thanks so much for the response guys. Really appreciate it. We have started the recovery process. Please kindly respond to any of my future comments. thanks once again.

Comment: The Back up works....!! Thanks guys....!!!

Comment: Great news! Now get regular backups in place so it doesn't happen again.